# How to divide a 2character string in 2 different strings in C?

Tags: c, string, split

I am writing a program in C and I have the following problem:

The user gives as input a two-character string, which contains one single digit number and one letter (for example 2B).

How can I divide it in one integer (2) and one character (B)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, but this is no tutoring service. Show your code and where your **specific** problem is.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if there is a function to do the job, such as strtok, because I have found nothing that can divide this string without containing a symbol.
Even if I send the code, which is incomplete, there is nothing relevant yet, exept from the command gets(input);

Comment: Do you care what the result is if the input did not match the 2-character digit-letter format?

Comment: @chux I don't have any problem in checking the validity of the input, I wanted to find out a way to accept a string that had a number from 0 to 9 and a letter behind it and if I could seperate the input in an integer and a character. I have already added a check after reading from the keyboard. Anyways, I found a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%c` specifier to get individual characters

```
char a, b;
printf("Give the 2char string");
scanf("%c%c", &a, &b);
printf("Char 1: %c\nChar2: %c", a, b);
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: Why not? It obtains two individual characters. Other solutions first take the  entire string from the standard input and then parse it. I directly obtain two characters using two %c specifiers. What's wrong? @Olaf

Comment: "How can I divide it in one integer (2) and one character (B)"

Comment: The OP can easily wite `a - '0'` to get the integer

Comment: @Olaf you are right, but I suppose that with this I can add atoi and change the character into a number. Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: @Nadia `atoi` takes a nul-terminated string.

Comment: @Nadia It is easier and faster to write `a - '0'`. Besides, `atoi` doesn't do error checking.

Comment: Would this be right?

int a;
char b;
printf("Give the 2char string");
scanf("%d%c", &a, &b);
printf("Number: %d\nChar: %c", a, b);

Comment: Yes, but `%d` allows multi-digit numbers, like 12.

Comment: @stackptr you are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code that you've tried, the obvious answer would be to assign the new values to variables based on index.

```
char buffer[] = "2B";
int num = (int) buffer[0] - '0';
char letter = buffer[1];
```

Comment: Why the braced initialiser instead of the obvious string literal? First rule for coding is to use language features for self-documenting code.

Comment: @Olaf because he is clearly new to C, so I wanted to demonstrate why you're able to use the index values to access a `char` in a string using them.

Comment: Especially for a beginner, one should focus on readability of the code. Note this is also read by others. This includes not to add unnecessary or problematic casts - why do you explicitly cast `buffer[0]`? Also you should avoid _magic numbers_. And explain the code.

Comment: When you replace the magic number with `'0'` for the purpose of legibility, ping me and I'll give this my upvote. Until then it's unfortunate that you encourage such non-portable and non-readable crud like `48`. :(